# Haskell: non-exhaustive-patterns

Tags: haskell, ghci, non-exhaustive-patterns

I am training for a test tomorrow to complete my introduction to functional programming but there is one thing I don't understand.

Whenever I have a program like:

```
test [] = []
test (x:xs) = test (xs)
```

What he does is that he takes the first element out of the list and continues with the rest. Whenever there is just one left, `xs` should be `[]` which in turn should trigger `test [] = []`. But whenever I run this algorithm I get an error. `Exception: <interactive>:20:5-16: Non-exhaustive patterns in function test.`

I couldn't find a clear explanation online. Could somebody please send me a link where this is explained clearly or explain it to me?

Comment: Weird. The code snippet you posted does not contain non-exhaustive patterns.

Comment: Just shooting in the dark: Are you perhaps trying to enter this definition into ghci? If so, you should use a single let statement: `let test [] = [] ; test (x:xs) = test xs`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing. Thank you very much.I already started freaking out because I spent this whole week programming recursions and I couldn't figure out why this one wouldn't work.

Comment: Personally, I prefer writing code in a file and loading into ghci. This is a good example of why you should do this. It would avoid this problem with a non-obvious solution.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The code you posted in the question's body *does* exhaustive pattern matching. However, if you try to enter this definition into ghci, you should use a *single* `let` statement:

```
Prelude> let test [] = [] ; test (x:xs) = test xs
```

---

What you are doing [here](http://s13.postimg.cc/a91hz516v/codesnippit.png) is incorrect. You are first defining a non-exhaustive function `test`:

```
Prelude> let test [] = []
```

And then you are defining *another* non-exhaustive function, also called `test`, which hides the first one:

```
Prelude> let test (x:xs) = test xs
```

Answer (score 4):

This is indeed a very tricky thing about trying out baby-programs in Haskell's REPL (GHCi).

Using `let` is not very obvious (esp., since it is not needed in a separate 'script/program').

And sometimes we do NOT want to create a full-fledged file but instead experiment with a small function with different 'cases'.

Another helpful approach is to use the delimiters `:{` & `:}` to define the extent of our function.

Say we want to try out a simple recursive `sum` function that can add up a List of Numbers. We would then say the following:

```
λ > :{
Prelude| sum [] = 0
Prelude| sum (x:xs) = x + sum xs
Prelude| :}
sum :: Num t => [t] -> t
Prelude
λ > sum [1..10]
55
it :: (Enum t, Num t) => t
```

Note how nicely we get to see the extent of our function now!

Hope this helps. Cheers!